# Windows Server 2012 C:\Windows\Installer occupying more than 200 GB

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-space-utilization

As the title says, I've been having a problem with a production WS 2012 R2 whose C:\Windows\Installer folder takes more than the 85% of the disk space. I tried the solution commented here: [Is it safe to delete files in C:\Windows\Installer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15746/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-in-c-windows-installer)

But I really cannot uninstall anything else and I don't think the problem is there since I barely have a SQL Server installed, an ERP client and another small app, nothing else.

As you can see in the picture below, the weight of this directory it's unbearable and I'm tired of having to extend the disk space because it does not help at all (4 days ago I extended it to 30 GB more and now they're gone as well.)

[Space taken by windows installer folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mlyJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was a corrupt packgage of Kaspersky Endpoint 11.3.x.x that was being copied over and over again.

Comment: Thank for the solution.